# Parece que tu instalación de PHP no cuenta con la extensión de MySQL

Tags: wordpress

Estoy migrando mi wordpress a un servidor VPS, pero estoy obteniendo este error, he probado hacer lo que dice este post pero no encuentro el php.ini, dentro de la carpeta de php5  solo tengo otra carpeta que es mods-available

https://uftech.wordpress.com/2017/01/20/solucion-parece-que-tu-instalacion-de-php-no-cuenta-con-la-extension-de-mysql-necesaria-para-hacer-funcionar-wordpress/

Nota: 
-he intentado migrar mi web pero cuando entro a http://miip/miweb/ obtengo el error mencionado arriba

-he intentado instalar otro wordpress desde 0 pero cuando entro a http://miip/testing/ la pagina sale en blanco

EDIT: ya elimine el ";" pero me sigue dando el mismo error, es normal que vean muchos ";"

```
; If you wish to have an extension loaded automatically, use the following
; syntax:
;
;   extension=modulename.extension
;
; For example, on Windows:
;
;   extension=msql.dll
;
; ... or under UNIX:
;
extension=msql.so
;
; ... or with a path:
;
;   extension=/path/to/extension/msql.so
```

Comment: Pon esto en un archivo PHP de prueba **`phpinfo();`** y luego lo abres en el navegador, ahí te dirá el estado actual de tu PHP, lo que hay instalado o no y lo que está habilitado a o no. Cuando hayas resuelto el problema no olvides de borrar ese archivo, no es bueno que dejes accesible la información de tu entorno PHP, ya que los hackers pueden sacar ventaja de ello.

Comment: @a.cedano editada mi pregunta Loaded Configuration File  /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files  /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d

Comment: Esto parece un problema de versions: en PHP 7 se eliminó la extensión mysql_* (obsoleta desde 5.5)

Comment: como puedo cambair la version a una 5 por ejemplo de mi wordpress

Comment: O sea ¿pusiste `phpinfo();` en un archivo y eso es lo que sale? Parece entonces que tienes problemas con la instalación de PHP en sí. ¿Estás en un hosting? Deberías contactar con soporte técnico.

Comment: esta instalado y corriendo php?

Comment: @sirdaiz ¿puedes actualizar a una versión más moderna de WP en lugar de bajar a una versión más antigua de PHP?

Comment: si puse un info.php, tengo contratado un vps

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro tengo peusto la utlima version de WP